# Browse For Reference not working in Visual Studio 2017 for Python Windows IoT

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I just got a new Raspberry Pi! when attempting to follow the official Microsoft tutorials I am running into a strange snag:
I am attempting to load package references into a Visual Studio Python project. 
The browse button doesn't show up, this problem appears to only be with the Windows 10 IoT project type in Python.

Anyone else run into this problem?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACiar.png)

Comment: Have you checked your project's Python environment?

Comment: I have tried it in all the Python environment settings possible.